# How to submit textures to the HTC Vive?

Tags: opengl, openvr, htc-vive

I've been trying to submit a texture to the HTC Vive using the compositor. I keep getting 105 errors which is "TextureUsesUnsupportedFormat". The Texture is a bmp image 24 bit Depth. I've looked at the hellovr sample and still a bit confused. I also saw that the Vive requires a RGBA8 format for the texture but not sure how to actually make one. I am trying to get the texture to fill up each Eye port.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my Code to retrieve the Texture and texture id:

```
Loading_Surf = SDL_LoadBMP("Test.bmp");
Background_Tx = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, Loading_Surf);


if (!Loading_Surf) {

    return 0;
}

glGenTextures(1, &textureid);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureid);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, Loading_Surf->w, Loading_Surf->h, 0, mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Loading_Surf->pixels);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

SDL_FreeSurface(Loading_Surf);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Background_Tx, NULL, NULL);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
return textureid;
```

Submitting to Vive Code:

```
vr::Texture_t l_Eye = { (void*)frameID, vr::API_OpenGL, vr::ColorSpace_Gamma };
std::cout << vr::VRCompositor()->WaitGetPoses(ViveTracked, vr::k_unMaxTrackedDeviceCount, NULL, 0);
error = vr::VRCompositor()->Submit(vr::Eye_Left, &l_Eye);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to create a surface with the correct RGBA8 format first, as mentioned in this answer: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/109067/6920

> Create a temporary surface (SDL_CreateRGBSurface) with the exact image
>   format you want, then copy Loading_Surf onto that temporary surface
>   (SDL_BlitSurface)

Answer (score 0):

`RGBA8` requires 32-bits. Your bitmap has only 24-bits. Seems like the `alpha` channels is missing.

Try to copy it into a bigger container that has `4x8-bit` = 32-bit per pixel (in c++ you can use `char` or you make use of some image library).

Or you figure out to feed your device with `RGB8` texture if something like that exists (play around with OpenGL).

This helps you https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture